# How to print out a table

Tags: python, list

I need help with printing out a table.
I want it to print as:

```
Name TotalHours

Jenny   34

Luke    28

Mike    20

Joanne  31

Tom     34
```

However, this happens -> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9TvU.jpg)

this is my code:

```
hrs_list = [[2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8],
              [7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4],
              [3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2],
              [9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1],
              [3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8]]

employees = ['Jenny', 'Luke', 'Mike', 'Joanne', 'Tom']


def total_hrs_and_salary():
    print("{} {:>15s} {:>15s}".format("Name", "TotalHours", "TotalSalary"))

    for names in employees:
        for lists in hrs_list:
            total = 0
            a = []
            i = 0
            for hrs in lists:
                total = total + hrs

            print("{} {:>15s}".format(names, total))
```

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: Thanks for posting in stack overflow,  don't Post Images as Text , as I tried to understand your question as per screenshot your able to achieve the output? need some improvement?

Comment: If you use `pandas`, try this: `pd.DataFrame({'Name': employees, 'TotalHours': [sum(hrs) for hrs in hrs_list]})`

Answer (score 0):

You could print it like this:

```
def total_hrs_and_salary():
    print("name\tTotalHours\n") 
    for i, name in enumerate(employees):
        print(f"{name}\t{sum(hrs_list[i])}\n")

total_hrs_and_salary()
```

output:

```
name    TotalHours

Jenny   34

Luke    28

Mike    20

Joanne  31

Tom     32
```